# Print Dialog Box Slow to open

Tags: printer, printing, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, network-printer

I have a client that we just migrated them from Server 2003 to Server 2008 and whenever they press the print button to open a print dialog box, it takes literally 30 seconds to open.  They are using Windows XP SP3.  They did not have this issue prior to putting in the Server 2008 box. Any ideas?

Thanks
msindle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed an old shared printer from the users printer window and it fixed the issue.